# Add where condition from another table in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

I have 2 tables: Person, Adress.
I want to :

```
select Person objects where the person.adress_Id = adress.id and adress.city = "new york".
```

The problem is I dont have `FK` between `Person` and `Adress` and as for now I cannot add it.

Is it possible to do this where?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use join in linq:

```
from person in dbContext.Persons
join address in dbContext.Addresses on person.address_id equals address.id
where address.city == "new york"
select new
{
    person.name,
    address.city,
    //others...
}
```

Comment: and if I dont want to select new type but the person object.

Comment: @SarahSh you cab simply select person.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it by using LINQ join

```
List<Person> persons = (from p in db.Persons
                       join a in db.Address
                       on p.adress_Id = a.adress.id
                       select p).ToList();
```